# Social network profile url creation in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a social network project based on codeignitor.

What I am trying to do is build a user profile url like:

```
http://domain.com/userid
```

I have tried

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/user/$1';
```

to redirect url but no luck. Does anyone have an idea of how to achive this without using .htaccess?

Comment: What's wrong with `.htaccess`? CodeIgniter [needs `.htaccess` to do this](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite)...

Comment: without .htaccess you can get http://domain.com/index.php/userid

Comment: This should work, but you will need setup route for all of your other controllers to overwrite the catch-all route you created here.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz yes this is the issue that i will need to define all controller in route.php.. Is using htacess is the optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend CI_Router.

You just need to add code that does a final check for username before giving up and calling the 404 page.